# Google Nexus 5 App Glitch

Tags: android

I've made an app in the play store, and it runs perfectly on every device I've tested it with, however one of my friends has a Nexus 5 and this really weird bug occurs. I can't post it as an image but here is a screenshot:

http://puu.sh/bO62x/452736745a.jpg

I'm not at home so I can't post the code but it's the same as any other app, just using startActivity.

Comment: i got a nexus 5 what is your app's name to test it?

Comment: Could be bad fragment stack management. Try the steps to reproduce it.

Comment: It's called Graal RC.

Comment: Yeah i can confirm this glitch too! But i really can't guess a cause! I noticed though that you change the apps orientation when the add is loaded, that may be of help to you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to provide a background colour.
It was only happening on some devices, the new data was being rendered over the top of the old. When you add a background colour it's rendered properly. e,g replaces the old view with the background colour it draws that then the data.